# Shouldn't pressure be dependent on volume?

Tags: forces, pressure, vector-fields

Pressure is defined as $\frac{F}{A}$ And while this makes sense when you are talking about pressure at the surface of a fluid, deep within a fluid it doesn't make sense, at least not to me.

It especially doesn't make sense to me if you are in a body of water. You will have forces coming from all directions. The force of gravity will pull you down and this gives the pressure at the top. The buoyant force provides a pressure from below. And water moves at different rates in different places so depending on where you are, you might or might not have equal pressures in each direction.

So shouldn't the total pressure be equivalent to the force of gravity at x distance from the center of mass and thus you would have 0 pressure if the water was perfectly still and you were in a position where gravity and buoyancy are balanced and more pressure in a given direction if there is more force pushing you in that direction than what is opposing it? But even then, it is still 3-dimensional so shouldn't volume be a factor in determining pressure instead of area being a factor?

Comment: You are dealing with sea currents...

Comment: this answer may help you https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/59764/226902

Comment: You are asking too many questions at once. I think that your many question would be better addressed by reading a basic textbook than by answers from this website. I would recommend Halliday Resnick and Walker (or a similar undergrad textbook). The textbook will discuss pressure.

Comment: Alternatively, edit your post to pose a single clear question. This might not feel good to you, but it will at least allow you to get a clear answer. Then you can ask your many other questions each as a separate post.

Comment: "Pressure is defined as F/A." No, it's really not that simple. Pressure is a scalar and force is a vector, so your proposed definition has to be supplemented by some explanation of how you are getting rid of the vector nature of the force. And, no, it is not just the magnitude of the force in general. (But the magnitude of the force is appropriate when the normal to the area of interest is oriented in the same direction as the force and the area is small enough that the force doesn't change in space.)

Comment: @hft note that this post is from 2017 and the OP hasn't been on the site in over a year

Comment: @BioPhysicist Heh. oops. Thanks. I guess it got bumped by a bot to the top of my home page...

Comment: Even this question is almost dead, I also will comment a bit ;-) Pressure and volume are related in Ideal gas law for gases, however liquid on contrary is assumed to be incompressible generally, so you can't push more water moles into same $V$ with the hopes to increase inner pressure. Hence pressure and volume is not related for liquids.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas While true, really the OP is making a typical error in just how definitions work, as hft's new answer points out. They are engaging in backwards thinking of some unclear notion of what they believe pressure to be, and then wondering why pressure isn't defined some other way.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I partly agree. However (albeit very rare situations) it can be that such opinions as OP really can help to clarify weak/ambiguous points of definitions if any or foster the creation of new definitions/concepts which can be valuable in Physics. Every view _counts_ for scientific progress (even bad ones).

Answer (score 1):

> Pressure is defined as $\frac{F}{A}$ And while this makes sense...

The pressure $p$ of a static fluid is the *normal* component of the surface force (magnitude of the surface force in the direction of the normal vector of the area being considered) per unit area, for a given "small enough" area (where small enough means the force effectively does not change over the area). More generally, pressure $p$ is defined via the diagonal part of the stress tensor
$$
\frac{1}{3}{\text Tr}\left(\sigma\right) = -p\;,
$$
and the force on a given volume $V$ is
$$
\vec F = \int_{V}d^3x \rho(\vec x, t)\vec f_B(\vec x,t) 
+ \oint_{\partial V}\sigma_{ij}(\vec x, t) n_j(\vec x)dA\;,
$$
where $\hat n$ is the normal vector to the area element $\vec {dA} = \hat n dA$. And where $\vec f_B$ represents body forces (e.g., gravity).

For a static fluid, the only part of the stress tensor that needs to be considered is the diagonal part, so the force reduces to:
$$
\vec F \to \int_{V}d^3x \rho(\vec x)\vec f_B(\vec x) 
- \oint_{\partial V}P(\vec x) \hat n dA\;.
$$
Supposing that a constant gravitational field $-g\hat z$ is the only force of interest further simplifies the equation:
$$
\vec F \to -M g\hat z
- \oint_{\partial V}P(\vec x) \hat n dA\;.
$$

> It especially doesn't make sense to me if you are in a body of water. You will have forces coming from all directions.

Yes.

> So shouldn't the total pressure be equivalent to the force of gravity at x distance from the center of mass and thus you would have 0 pressure if the water was perfectly still and you were in a position where gravity and buoyancy are balanced and more pressure in a given direction if there is more force pushing you in that direction than what is opposing it?

Not really. I mean, this question does not even make sense.

> But even then, it is still 3-dimensional so shouldn't volume be a factor in determining pressure instead of area being a factor?

Again, this can not really be answered since it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a body of fluid of density $ \rho$ at a depth $h$ below the surface,

The net pressure acting would be

$P= \rho gh$

Remember that pressure is defined to be force acting per **unit area** of surface i.e., Pressure is always considered to be acting normal to the surface( This is why even though it has a direction, it's considered scalar or more precisely tensor).

So, if were to calculate the force acting on the top surface of a body at a depth $h$ in a fluid of density $\rho$ with top surface area $A$,

$F=(\rho gh)A$

So, your consideration in 3-dimensional sense would be to determine the force acting and not the pressure.

Comment: So, right in the area where gravity and buoyancy are balanced, if there are forces of the same magnitude in all horizontal directions, the total force may be 0 but the pressure from those forces would be positive.